# Can I work remotely for US client while visiting US on Travel (B-2) visa?

Tags: usa, visa

I work for a US client remotely from home in India. My cousin who has a business in USA has invited me to visit USA for 6 months. I will be staying with him and we both will be visiting many cities in USA as tourists. He will be paying for all of my trip as I do not have sufficient funds to fund my trip on my own.
Can I work remotely for my US employer while in US?
Will I have any issues getting B-2 visa as I am working remotely for my US employer?
Should I mention in immigration that I will be working remotely?
Will I have to pay taxes in US if I work remotely for my employer?

Comment: In your question on [travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81886/can-i-work-remotely-for-us-client-while-visiting-us-on-travel-b-2-visa) you wrote that the purpose of your visit would be to help your cousin with his business. You should include that detai in this quetionl here too.

Comment: We have put that on hold for now.